# Reason for breakdown of a nice binomial identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

One has the nice identities
$${xy\choose 1}={x\choose 1}{y\choose 1},$$
$${xy+1\choose 2}={x+1\choose 2}{y+1\choose 2}+{x\choose 2}{y\choose 2}$$
and
$${xy+2\choose 3}={x+2\choose 3}{y+2\choose 3}+4{x+1\choose 3}{y+1\choose 3}+{x\choose 3}{y\choose 3}.$$

(The proof is essentially trivial by interpreting ${z\choose k}$ as a polynomial of degree $k$.)

This sequence of identities stops: There seems to be no nice expression of ${xy+k-1\choose k}$ as a linear combination of
${x+k-i\choose k}{y+k-i\choose k},i=1,\ldots,k$ for $k\geq 4$.

*Is there a good reason for this breakdown?* (Probably a better question is: Is there a reason for these identities to hold for $k=2$ and, especially, for $k=3$?)

Comment: Is it a coincidence that 1; 1,1; 1,4,1 is the Eulerian numbers sequence?

Comment: No idea if this is coincidental. Coefficients on the right hand side should however add up to $k!$ (by comparing coefficients of $(xy)^k$ on both sides).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

$\def\des{\operatorname{des}}$Let $\des(\pi)$ be the number of descents of the permutation $\pi$. Then for any permutation $\pi$ in $S_k$, we have
\begin{equation*}\binom{xy+k-\des(\pi)-1}{k} =\sum_{\sigma\tau=\pi}\binom{x+k-\des(\tau)-1}{k}
\binom{y+k-\des(\sigma)-1}{k}.\tag{$*$}\label{star}
\end{equation*}

If $\pi$ is the identity then $\des(\pi)=0$, so the left side of \eqref{star} is $\binom{xy+k-1}{k}$ and on the right, $\tau=\sigma^{-1}$. The OP's identities correspond to the fact that if $k\le 3$ then the number of descents of $\pi$ is the same as the number of descents of $\pi^{-1}$, but this is not true for $k>3$. This also explains the occurrence of the Eulerian numbers as coefficients for $k\le3$.

As far as I know, the earliest proof of \eqref{star} is in
Bogdan Mielnik and Jerzy Plebański,
*[Combinatorial approach to Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff exponents](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIHPA_1970__12_3_215_0)*,
Annales de l’I. H. P., section A, tome 12, no 3 (1970), pp. 215–254 (see equation (11.10));  further references can be found in Jason Fulman and T. Kyle Petersen,
*[Card shuffling and P-partitions](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2004.01659)*, arXiv:2004.01659 [math.CO].

Comment: Very nice explanation! Thanks.

Comment: MathJax notes: as with TeX, you can use `\label`+`\eqref` with `\tag` and get nice hyperlinks to boot.  *Unlike* TeX, MathJax is not aggressive about discarding whitespace, so a preamble line `$\def\des{…}$` followed by a newline will force a space in the text.  Unfortunately, as ugly as it is in the source, the only way to get rid of the space is to put the closing `$` directly next to the first line of the post, with no intervening whitespace.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: is it implied that $\pi = \tau \sigma$?

Comment: @NooneAtAll If $\sigma\tau$ is the identity then so is $\tau\sigma$ but in general $\tau\sigma\ne\sigma\tau$.